# Can Rendering Be Paused And Continued?

Tags: rendering

Just curious to get an idea of how it works, could I pause a project to shutdown my PC for the night and then continue the next day, as I'm aware it can take a long time to render some projects.

It's different from the question it's been link to for similarities, in the sense that it wouldn't be in the same session, the PC would  be turned of then back on, it's a difference worth considering.

Comment: It looks like a duplicate at first, but to a closer inspection, the other question deals with an uninterrupted session, while this one asks about turning off the computer altogether. The answer is the same though: there's no such functionality at the moment.

Comment: If you are rendering using Cycles, this method https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/87487/16395, together with using "progressive refine", could help. Of course, instead of two computers at the same moment, that can be applied to the same computer on different days.

Comment: Are you render animation or still image?

Comment: I think a difference this slight should be ignored. I would consider it a duplicate. It is the same question in essence.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I'd be exploring both animation and still images I just wanted to be sure as I've been recommended Render Farms and just wasn't sure if it was worth it, the other topic didn't quite give me the answer I was looking for, given that im asking about the PC being turned of rather than a part of the same session apologies if it created an issue.

Comment: If your PC  and operating system supports 'Hibernate' then you may simply be able to hibernate and then resume the following morning. You would need to try it to ensure it works as expected (I don't know if GPUs reliably hibernate and resume.... I would assume so) - there could be glitches if your particular hardware isn't 100% supported.

Comment: It does have a hibernate option, never used it but will give it a test tonight to see how efficient it is, brilliant awnser thank you